# Solving $\int \frac{\sqrt{1-(f'(x))^2}}{f(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function satisfying $f(x) >0$ and $|f'(x)| \leq 1 $ for all $x$. Is it possible to solve the indefinite integral 
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\sqrt{1-(f'(x))^2}}{f(x)}dx
\end{equation}
in terms of $f(x)$? I suspect that it is not possible but perhaps I am overlooking a nice substitution. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that there is a general formula. For example, for a function as simple as $f(x) = \ln x$ (which satisfies the requirements on a restricted domain) Mathematica gives up (which almost always means that it has concluded by the Risch algorithm that no elementary antiderivative exists).

However, for $f(x) = a\ x^b$, we have the nice result $$\int \frac{\sqrt{1-f'(x)^2}}{f(x)} dx  = - \frac{\sqrt{1-f'(x)^2} + ab \arcsin\left(f'(x) \right)} {a(b-1)x^{b-1}}.$$